# Visual Studio Code language templates

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a option to create new files like in Eclipse? When I create a new file in Eclipse, there is a dialog with classname, main method, etc.

I want to do this in Visual Studio Code too. I don't really want to write a class from nothing by myself :D.

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not supported. Visual Studio Code is more lightweight than Eclipse and Visual Studio.